# regex: word must end with one of given characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex that captures the following

- starts with a literal `%`
- can contain 0-unlimited characters of any kind, but
- must end with one of the following `[diouxXeEfFgGcrs]`
- immediately following one of the above characters there should be a word boundary (`\b`)

The regex I tried is this: `%.*?[diouxXeEfFgGcrs]\b` The problem is with something like `%y %s`. What I want instead is for the `%y` to be skipped and the `%s` to be captured.

Here is a [link](https://regex101.com/r/cBqHpm/4) to a regex101.

Comment: Does your second condition include `word boundary` ? If no then I guess [this might work.](https://regex101.com/r/cBqHpm/5)

Comment: This sounds like a very strange requirement. Try [`%([diouxXeEfFgGcrs]\B|[^diouxXeEfFgGcrs])*[diouxXeEfFgGcrs]\b`](https://regex101.com/r/diNNef/1). However, I do not quite get what the output should look like.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%+[^%]*?[diouxXeEfFgGcrs]\b
```

Try this.See demo.

UPDATED DEMO HERE
https://regex101.com/r/cBqHpm/8

Comment: this is very close, but I also want to capture `%%s`

Comment: ah yes, perfect! I took the liberty up updating the link to the new regex

Comment: @stoebelj np...do test it thoroughly though :)